# JUnit for RestController with parameter PersistentEntityResourceAssembler

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit

could you please help me.

I try to implement an JUnit-Test for a Restcontroller with parameter PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.

Here is my RestController:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController

public class GreetingController2 {

    @Autowired
    ProducerTemplate pt;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Greeting> updateGreeting(  PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler,   
             @RequestHeader HttpHeaders header, @RequestBody Greeting greeting) {

         Map<String, Object> headers = (Map) header.toSingleValueMap();

        greeting=(Greeting) pt.requestBodyAndHeaders("direct:start", greeting, headers);

        return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(greeting, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And my JunitTest:

```
public class GreetingControllerMocksTest2 extends AbstractControllerTest2 {

    @Mock
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;


    @InjectMocks
    private GreetingController2 greetingController2;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Initialize Mockito annotated components
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        // Prepare the Spring MVC Mock components for standalone testing
        setUp(greetingController2);
    }


    @Test
    public void testRestEndpoint() throws Exception {

        // Create some test data
        Greeting entity = new Greeting(5,"Rudi");

        // Stub the GreetingService.update method return value
       when(producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(anyString(),anyObject(),
       anyObject())).thenReturn(entity);

        // Perform the behavior being tested
        String uri = "/greeting2";
        String inputJson = super.mapToJson(entity);

        MvcResult result = mvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(uri)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(inputJson))
                .andReturn();

        // Extract the response status and body
        String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        int status = result.getResponse().getStatus();

        // Verify the GreetingService.update method was invoked once
        verify(producerTemplate, 
          times(1)).requestBodyAndHeaders(anyString(),anyObject(),anyObject());

        // Perform standard JUnit assertions on the test results
        Assert.assertEquals("failure - expected HTTP status 200", 200, status);
        Assert.assertTrue(
                "failure - expected HTTP response body to have a value",
                content.trim().length() > 0);
        Greeting updatedEntity = super.mapFromJson(content, Greeting.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull("failure - expected entity not null",
                updatedEntity);
    }

 }
```

When starting the junit-test i get the following Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.<init>()
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
    at org.example.ws.web.api.GreetingControllerMocksTest2.testRestEndpoint(GreetingControllerMocksTest2.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    ... 52 more
```

If i remove the paramter PersistentEntityResourceAssembler, then everthing works fine. But der RestController is generated by a tool, so it is not possible for me to remove this.

Answer (score 0):

From your controller method I don't see if you are using PersistentEntityResourceAssembler. Please check your use case. To fix this, in your controller, you can use @RepositoryRestController instead of @RestController. Please check http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers. I found the similar issue has been reported for some different use case. This issue is still in open state. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-657

Comment: Thanks for yout help, but it doesn't work. I changed the controller but I have still the same error. The Controller was generated by a tool, so I can not remove PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.

Comment: What error did you get after this change? Did you try hitting your service using Postman?

Comment: The error is org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.<init>()
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.

Comment: httprequester says: ERROR 8148 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.<init>

I don't know why it works in production invironment

Comment: Error above, if I use annotation "RestController", if i use "RepositoryRestController" then "405 Method Not Allowed".

Comment: Now I checked also  https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-657. There is a suggestion (WebMvcConfigurerAdapter ) to solve the problem. But it also was not successful.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have missed something.
I faced this error and fixed it, the problem was that I forgot to add an annotation @RequestBody to the parameter of the method.
Next code works fine:

```
//interface:
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public Message greeting(@RequestBody GreetingRequestMessage requestMessage);

//implementation:
public Message greeting(@RequestBody GreetingRequestMessage requestMessage) {
}

//setup @Before:
mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(testObj).build();
GreetingRequestMessage requestMessage = new GreetingRequestMessage();
payloadString = mapper.writeValueAsString(requestMessage);

//test:
payloadString = mapper.writeValueAsString(request);
mvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/greeting")
                    .content(payloadString)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().is(202));
```