# How do I set up unit tests for RepositoryRestController in Spring?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have the following configuration for my unit test for a `RepositoryRestController` (the `MyController` class):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class MyTest {

    @Configuration
    @EnableSpringDataWebSupport
    static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        MyController myController() {
            //controller construction
        }
    }

}
```

I can't find any documents online expounding on what sort of config I need to setup to get the tests running correctly. I only stumbled upon `EnableSpringDataWebSupport` when I was having trouble injecting `Pageable` instance on the controller method I'm testing. Now, my problem is that `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` doesn't get autowired because the log says it has no default constructor. How does Spring setup this up?

As for the duplication with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658333), notice that my configuration is not all that much different from the accepted answer and I'm still having problems. `@WebMvcTest` implies `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`. I've exhausted most of the information I could search about this problem before posting this question.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962330/rest-controllers-vs-spring-data-rest-repositoryrestresource

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing a custom RepositoryRestController that uses a PersistentEntityResourceAssembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658333/testing-a-custom-repositoryrestcontroller-that-uses-a-persistententityresourceas)

Comment: Also see here: http://www.springboottutorial.com/unit-testing-for-spring-boot-rest-services

Comment: Downvoting because question is very broad (many ways to test with Spring), and spring has excellent documentation that should help getting much further than what the question provides.

Comment: @tkruse Then you should have pointed me to where the documentation is. I know how to test a regular REST controller, and I have specified in the configuration I'm currently using and the specific issue I'm having trouble with. I have also seen that link to that SO question before I posted this question. You should know that the answer to that question is pretty much what I have on my setup already.

Comment: also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311001/junit-for-restcontroller-with-parameter-persistententityresourceassembler

Comment: Also you should add the log error output

Answer (score 0):

If you have @PageableDefault in your controller, this is the general setting for controller test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(YourController.class)
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport  // for Pageable resolve
public class YourControllerTest {

}
```